# server redirect inside public shared function

Tags: ajax, vb.net, redirect

I have a ajax call happening for the java script which is this.

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function Finalize()
        try
             Sendemail1()
             sendemail2()
             doesomething()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorMSg = -1
            Throw ex
        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
      Return "success"
    End Function
```

if there is a success then i am handing that on client side and want to redirect page to a different one. but i dont know why system never reach to the Success: or Error: or Complete: of the Ajax call. If i remove all three internal Public Shared Function then it works as expected.

```
Public Shared Function Sendemail1()
    '''' Send email
End Function

Public Shared Function Sendemail2()
   '''' Send email
End Function

Public Shared Function doesomething()
 '''' Update database
End Function
```

as i explain i want to redirect to a different page when all the function are completed. I tired adding

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("MyPage.aspx")
```

at the end of third public shared function and redirection didnt happen.

I also tried adding that after the call of third function in the main Ajax call, still nothing happen.

Am i missing something here. What is the proper way to resolve this issue.

Client side Code:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
var userConfirmation = window.confirm('Are you sure?\nPress OK to continue.\nPress CANCEL to stop the process.'); 
    if (userConfirmation == false) { 
    return 0;
    }
    else { 
             $.ajax
                 ({
                     type: 'POST',
                     //url: 'NewSubmission.aspx/function1',
                     url: 'NewSubmission.aspx/FinalizeSub',
                     data: JSON.stringify({ id:193, SubType:1, Exception:0, PageNum:12, Authors:1 }),
                     //data: '{sessionval: '' + data1 + '' }',
                     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                     dataType: 'json',
                     success: OnSuccess,
                     failure: function (response) {
                         alert(response.d);
                     },
                     Error: function (response) {
                         alert(response.d);
                     },
                    Complete: function (response) {
                         alert(response.d);
                     }


                 }); 

     function OnSuccess(data) {
    alert(data.d);
  /// Redirection will heppen here
}

 } 
});
</script>
```

PS:i also don't see an error messages on the browser console.

Comment: If you're handling the response in JavaScript code then you'd need to perform your redirect in JavaScript code.  AJAX doesn't follow redirect headers.  Because, well, interacting with the server *without* changing the current page context is entirely the point of using AJAX.  As for never reaching your JavaScript success handlers... Where is your actual JavaScript code here?  Is it successfully sending the AJAX request to the server?  What is the server's response?  If the problem is client-side, show your *client-side* code.

Comment: The ajax calls a webpage and gets the value returned, if you redirect, it will redirect in the ajax call before returning the value. If you want to redirect to be done on the client, then the javascript should redirect on a success.

Comment: @David please see my client side code update. I can reach the Success if i remove all three internal method but not if they are there. Two of three method will send email via smtp if that helps you in any way.

Comment: @Arpan: You have a `success` callback, but you don't seem to have an `error` callback.  (JavaScript is case-sensitive.)  In fact, you seem to be randomly adding possible callbacks and just hoping something will work.  That's not effective.  Change `Error` to `error`, and also use your browser's debugging tools to examine the actual response from the server to see what it is.  Currently you're wafting between two problems/questions.  (1) If your server-side code is failing in some way or returning an error response, you need to debug.  (2) If you want to redirect, do so in JavaScript.

Comment: @David thanks for pointing out on  "Error". that totally slipped my mind and was not. My server side code was never failing. it was executing file and reaching at the Return statement. When i replace "Error" with "error" i saw that its giving me json.parse error. I have to  change the dataType: 'html', and that fixed the issue and now my code is reaching success callback. I am redirecting the page in success in client side so everything seem to working as expected. thanks for your help.